# Java Android - IndexOf &Offset

Tags: substring, indexof

I am trying to read from a text file but and those Strings separate into different attributes but I don't know how to follow after the first split.

Here is my code: What should be the offset of the `getType()` string?

```
try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("Autoeval");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         //Skips lines
        for (int i = 0; i< questionNumber; i++) {
            reader.readLine();
        }

        question = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public String getId() {

    return question.substring(0, question.indexOf(";"));
}
public String getType() {
    return question.substring(question.indexOf(";"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's **ugly**, but why don't you create 2 global private variables:

```
private String _id;
private String _type;
```

Then, after you read in the question, you can do this:

```
{
    //stuff

    question = reader.readLine();

    _id = question.substring(0, question.indexOf(";"));
    _type = question.substring(_id.length); // assuming no other ";" delimiters

}

public String getId() {
    return _id;
}

public String getType() {
    return _type;
}
```

All this being said, there are much better ways to do this.